# Store tests trend without test results data

Tags: charts, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I want to see test trend for 1 month for example on a Dashboard or whatever. But I limit my jobs to max 10 stored builds because they take a lot of space. Can I somehow store data about passes/failed tests so the charts can be displayed and not store hundreds of builds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend separating your build job (the one that constructs libraries and executables and that likely has large artifacts) from your test job (the one that executes tests). This allows you to control aspects of the test job independently of the build job, including how long to keep build results.

Using the [Copy Artifacts plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin) you can make the build artifacts available to the test job.

Comment: This looks like a really nice solution. Sadly this multiplies the amount of jobs. Right now we have about 20, so making separate tests will blow everything up :). Anyway thanks. I can categorize with views

Answer (score 2):

We use the plugin 'Plot plugin'.
It saves values in 'property' files which are saved in the workspace folder. So the data is not lost when the build folders are gone. Each build appends it's results to the 'property' file.

You can configure a plot to include any number of builds.

Here is an example of one of the plots it has been making for us over the last year or so:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Cool idea. I clear workspace before each build but this can work